# Exiting a method with a specific string

Tags: java, string, methods, while-loop

I'm still relatively new at Java and am working on a program for class. I have everything coded up and it's working great, but I need to exit a method when I type the string "exit". My current code will be below. I must have 3 methods (includes main) and a "while" loop (or do-while, but my professor has barred us from using those) as per the assignment. It's a "magic eight ball" program and the while loop is set to continue asking questions until the user types "exit" but I can't seem to get my "while" loop to work correctly. If I type exit as the first string it'll exit like it's supposed to, but if I type any other string it'll keep running, even after I type exit, and basically becomes an infinite loop of questions/answers. Any help is appreciated.

A side note, those numbers in the switch statement are purely place holders for future answers, so ignore them.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FirstProblem {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        getQuestion();
    }

    public static String getQuestion () {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("Ask any question you need answered and prepare yourself for the sage advice of......your computer.\nJust type \"exit\" when you can't handle the truth any longer.\nQuestion: ");
        String question = input.nextLine();
        String exit = "exit";
        showAnswer();
        while (!question.equals(exit)) {
            getQuestion();
        }
        return question;
    }

    public static void showAnswer () {
        int answer = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        switch (answer) {
            case 0: System.out.println ("1"); break;
            case 1: System.out.println ("2"); break;
            case 2: System.out.println ("3"); break;
            case 3: System.out.println ("4"); break;
            case 4:System.out.println ("5"); break;
            case 5:System.out.println ("6"); break;
            case 6:System.out.println ("7"); break;
            case 7: System.out.println ("8"); break;
            case 8: System.out.println ("9"); break;
            case 9: System.out.println ("10"); break;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this code:

```
        showAnswer();
        while (!question.equals(exit)) {
            getQuestion();
        }
```

This is doing a recursive call, if you don't know what recursion is read about it here at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

The solution would be to change it to:

```
        while (!question.equals(exit)) {
            showAnswer();
            System.out.print("Question: ");
            question = input.nextLine();
        }
```

Here's the code snippet [on Ideone](https://ideone.com/vFkMJW).

Answer (score 1):

Change the call inside the while loop from:

```
while (!question.equals(exit)) {
    getQuestion();
}
```

to:

```
while (!question.equals(exit)) {
    return getQuestion(); // <-- return here

}
```

**Explanation:**
Since that is a [`recursive`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) call, when you finally type "exit" this answer exists only in the [`scope`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) of the last call, this call returns to the previous call in which the question was different than "exit" and hence it displays the question again and again...

---

**Reply to the comment about getting rid of the last answer:**

If you don't want to display the answer after the user typed "exit" you can modify `showAnswer()` to do so by passing it the question, and if it equals to "exit" bailout before doing the printing:

```
public static String getQuestion () {
    ...
    showAnswer(question);
    ...
}

public static void showAnswer (String question) {
    if ("exit".equals(question)) return;
    ...
}
```

Comment: on typing exit program will stopped but answer is showing . how can i get rid of it?