# Methods, loops and randoms, oh my

Tags: java, loops, methods

I have an assignment at school to create a program with at least three separate methods that will act like a 'Magic Eight Ball".  I have already created the method with 10 'responses' set to a 'switch' statement, based on a separate method that generates a random number between 0 and 9.  What I need is a 'for', 'while', or 'do while' loop method that is supposed to continue asking questions until the word 'exit' is entered as a question.  then I need a way to tie all of these methods together so they work right.  I use a program called BlueJ (as instructed by the prof)

What I have so far is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MagicEightBall
{
    //Input method
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

       startAsking();            
   }
   //Loop method
    public static void startAsking()
   {
       do
       {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
           System.out.print("Enter Question: ");
           System.out.println("Entering 'exit' ends program ");
            if(input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
            break;
            System.out.println(getResponse());
       }
        while(true);
        //input.close();
   }   
   //Output method     
   public static String getResponse()   
   {
       int numberOfResponses = 10;
       int response = (int)(Math.random() * numberOfResponses);
       String responseString;
       switch (response)
       {
            case 1: System.out.println("Of course!  H-A-L said so");
            case 2: System.out.println("Yes, my young Padawan!");
            case 3: System.out.println("V-ger has informed me that your answer is 'Yes'");
            case 4: System.out.println("Mr. Spock says 'Not a chance, Captain'");
            case 5: System.out.println("Only when Pi = apple would that be a 'Yes'");
            case 6: System.out.println("There is no try, only do, or do not");
            case 7: System.out.println("You know 'Big Brother' heard you ask that question?");
            case 8: System.out.println("SyStEm MaLfUnCtIoN! pLeAsE tRy l8r");
            case 9: System.out.println("No.  That would cause a food fight");
            default: System.out.println("I'm sorry, it's time for my oil bath");
       }
       return responseString;
   }   
}
```

Any help as to how to complete this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you covered arrays yet? That's not a great solution.

Comment: We have, but in a very limited capacity.  What i currently have is nowhere near complete, it is mostly me just putting stuff in there hoping a revelation comes to me on how to complete it.  I'm not opposed to using an array, but i know very little about them.

Comment: Well, if you think carefully about that `switch` you'll see it *could* map very easily to an array of response strings allowing you do immediately retrieve the response with the generated number.

Comment: While these repsonses are appreciated, I'm afraid they are still a bit over my head.  We read about arrays, but were not allowed to implement them into our programs, so I have zero exposure to them other than knowing they can contain several things that can be called later.  I am also following a post on here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195203/exiting-a-method-with-a-specific-string - and it appears that using the help on this page creates an infinite loop.  Even trying to change the names of his methods to match mine, it still doesn't work right

Answer (score 0):

I build your code , then run it ;
reading about what are u asking its seems do everything (but not 100% correct) , in this steps:
1 ask u a question
2 answer u random
3 if asked "exit" he stop the program

can u explain me better what miss in your program that you need ? not doing at the moment?

for now i just can say you use a variable for append the question , than use the variable for go put from the loop also there is something not needed in the getresponse method

```
import java.util.*;
public class NewClass
{
    //Input method
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

       startAsking();            
   }
   //Loop method
    public static void startAsking()
   {
       do
       {

           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
           System.out.print("Enter Question: ");
           System.out.println("Entering 'exit' ends program ");
            if(input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
            break;
           getResponse();

       }
        while(true);
        //input.close();
   }   
   //Output method     
   public static void getResponse()   
   {
       int numberOfResponses = 10;
       int response = (int)(Math.random() * numberOfResponses);
       System.out.println(response);

       switch (response)
       {
            case 1: System.out.println("Of course!  H-A-L said so");break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Yes, my young Padawan!");break;
            case 3: System.out.println("V-ger has informed me that your answer is 'Yes'");break;
            case 4: System.out.println("Mr. Spock says 'Not a chance, Captain'");break;
            case 5: System.out.println("Only when Pi = apple would that be a 'Yes'");break;
            case 6: System.out.println("There is no try, only do, or do not");break;
            case 7: System.out.println("You know 'Big Brother' heard you ask that question?");break;
            case 8: System.out.println("SyStEm MaLfUnCtIoN! pLeAsE tRy l8r");break;
            case 9: System.out.println("No.  That would cause a food fight");break;
            default: System.out.println("I'm sorry, it's time for my oil bath");
       }


   }   
}
```

dont care about some output i add for control the loop

Comment: look at the spoiler just if you can't recognize the errors by your self